# Как вызвать конструктор в каждом унаследованом классе?

Tags: php, ооп, классы, наследование

Есть код

```
// Главный класс  
class MainClass {
    public function __construct(){
        // Инициализация основной информации (БД, язык сайта, группая пользователя и т.п.)
    }
}


// Класс-батя для всех страниц
class Page extends MainClass {
    public function __construct(){
        // Инициализация переменных для шаблонизатора, одинаковых для всех страниц (например, футер)
    }
}


// Клаас отдельной страницы
class IndexPage extends Page {
    public function __construct(){
        // Инициализация переменных для шаблонизатора, индивидуальных для данной страницы
    }
}
```

В каждом классе иницилизируются свои переменные, но, как я понял, любой новый конструкторов в классе перебивает все предыдущие, как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class IndexPage extends Page {
    public function __construct(){
        MainClass::__construct();
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Но в целом тут явные проблемы с архитектурой

Comment: Я стырил архитектуру с unreal engine 4

Comment: А как бы вы предложили организовать её?

Comment: С игрового движка в веб-приложение? Волшебно.

Comment: MainClass надо просто выкинуть. У классов не должно быть принудительных родителей за исключением тех, которые проставляет сам язык. Создавать по классу на страницу тоже не нужно, потому что сам класс явно не тем будет заниматься, и настоящая логика вроде "засунуть данные в шаблонизатор" должна лежать в других компонентах.